# Guardar entrada do usuário num loop

Tags: java, array, array-multidimensional

Pretendo obter a lista da variável `numeros`, gerados pelo seguinte loop:

```
Scanner kb = new Scanner (System.in);
double [] numeros= new double[10];
for (int i = 0; i < numeros.length; i++)
{
    System.out.println("o proximo numero");

    numeros[i] = kb.nextDouble();
}
```

A minha dúvida é como armazenar a lista gerada desta `array`.

Comment: E qual a duvida?

Comment: A minha dúvida é como armazenar a lista gerada desta array.

Comment: Seria interessante editar a pergunta, pois ela não está no formato de uma.

Comment: @cambine editei a tua pergunta, ela está um pouco confusa, você pode [editá-la](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/154544/edit) ou reverter ao [estado anterior](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/154544/revisions).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> A minha dúvida é como armazenar a lista gerada desta `array`.

Na linha `numeros[i] = ...` se eu entendi bem, você já faz isso, guarda no `array` o que for digitado na entrada que possa ser lido como um `double`.

Como sugestão, você pode usar [`Scanner.html#hasNextDouble`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextDouble--) antes para verificar se o conteúdo digitado pode ser interpretado como um valor `double`:

```
Scanner kb = new Scanner (System.in);
double [] numeros = new double [10];

for (int i = 0; i < numeros.length; i++) {
    System.out.println("Digite o próximo número: ");

    if(kb.hasNextDouble()) { 
        numeros[i] = kb.nextDouble();
    }
}
```

Para exibir o conteúdo do `array`, você pode fazer assim:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(numeros));
```

Ou assim:

```
for (double numero: numeros) {
    System.out.println(numero);
}
```

<kbd>[Ver **DEMO**](http://ideone.com/500gpE)</kbd>